# Magento Error 500 when displaying specific categorie with ?limit=64 parameter

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I recently discover (with webmaster tools) that i have an error 500 on working Magento 1.8 install.

The hosting is a dedicated server with Centos 6.7, PHP 5.4 with memory_limit 1024M and max_execution_time 180.

The error only occured when the page is called with the ?limit=16 OR =32 OR =64 parameter (the error is instantly displayed, no wait time).

There's only 8 products on this page and any other value for limit will not produce the error.

I have tested changing the limit value on other categorie pages and all of the ones i have tested does indeed worked.

No Magento report created but can found this in http/error_log :

```
[Wed Mar 09 15:48:16 2016] [warn] [client my.ip] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://domain.tld/categorie/categorie/categorie/categorie.html
[Wed Mar 09 15:48:16 2016] [error] [client my.ip] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://domain.tld/categorie/categorie/categorie/categorie.html
```

In magento/var/log/system.log

```
2016-03-09T14:48:14+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /var/www/vhosts/gulliver-modeles.fr/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php on line 66
```

In magento/var/log/exception.log

```
2016-03-09T14:48:14+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Type de bloc non valide : Mage_Manufacturer_Block_Manufacturer' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Type de bloc no...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('manufacturer/ma...', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(164): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('manufacturer/ma...', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(134): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(504): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<p>{{block type...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Widget/Block.php(69): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<p>{{block type...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Cms_Block_Widget_Block->_beforeToHtml()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('before_body_end', true)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('before_body_end')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#26 {main}
```

I tried to clean Magento cache and reindex all products with no success...

So what can i do next and why if there's a block problem, not all pages are affected ?

Answer (score 0):

as what it says in your "system.log" its an array to string conversion error. You should only pass number to your "limit" parameter

Comment: Thanks for your return but i exprimate myself wrong, when i said that there is problem with ?limit=[16,32,64], i was trying to said ?limit=16 OR ?limit=32 OR ?limit=64.

The page is also working with ?limit=all by the way so not only number can be used ! ;- P